# Why does RDS PostgreSQL always recover on restart?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, aws, postgresql-9.6

I am running an RDS instance of PostgreSQL 9.6.3: `select version();` returns `PostgreSQL 9.6.3 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [...]`.

I have found that after issuing a stop from the RDS console followed by a start the database always reports that the database system was not properly shutdown, requiring recovery. This behavior has been independently verified by at least one other RDS PostgreSQL user (https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=809401#809401).

The query

```
select name, setting
from pg_settings
where name in ('fsync', 'wal_sync_method', 'synchronous_commit');
```

reports that `fsync = on`, `wal_sync_method = fdatasync` (correct for a Linux system), and `synchronous_commit = on`.

I see the following in the logs after issuing a stop:

```
2017-10-12 16:37:36 UTC::@:[3464]:LOG: received fast shutdown request
2017-10-12 16:37:36 UTC::@:[3464]:LOG: aborting any active transactions
2017-10-12 16:37:36 UTC::@:[3515]:LOG: autovacuum launcher shutting down
2017-10-12 16:37:36 UTC::@:[3512]:LOG: shutting down
2017-10-12 16:37:36 UTC::@:[3512]:LOG: checkpoint starting: shutdown immediate
2017-10-12 16:37:36 UTC::@:[3512]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 1 buffers (0.0%); 0 transaction log file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.007 s, sync=0.002 s, total=0.145 s; sync files=1, longest=0.002 s, average=0.002 s; distance=16384 kB, estimate=16402 kB
2017-10-12 16:37:36 UTC::@:[3464]:LOG:  database system is shut down
```

And the following after issuing a start:

```
2017-10-12 17:05:33 UTC::@:[3293]:LOG: database system was interrupted; last known up at 2017-10-12 16:37:50 UTC
2017-10-12 17:05:33 UTC::@:[3293]:LOG: database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2017-10-12 17:05:33 UTC::@:[3293]:LOG: redo starts at 165/1160
2017-10-12 17:05:33 UTC::@:[3293]:LOG: unexpected pageaddr 164/D2000000 in log segment 000000010000016500000003, offset 0
2017-10-12 17:05:33 UTC::@:[3293]:LOG: redo done at 165/20000A0
2017-10-12 17:05:33 UTC::@:[3293]:LOG: last completed transaction was at log time 2017-10-12 16:50:53.823582+00
2017-10-12 17:05:33 UTC::@:[3293]:LOG: checkpoint starting: end-of-recovery immediate
2017-10-12 17:05:33 UTC::@:[3293]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 2 buffers (0.0%); 0 transaction log file(s) added, 0 removed, 3 recycled; write=0.029 s, sync=0.002 s, total=0.046 s; sync files=2, longest=0.002 s, average=0.001 s; distance=49147 kB, estimate=49147 kB
2017-10-12 17:05:33 UTC::@:[3293]:LOG: MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
```

Given my understanding of PostgreSQL's (fast) shutdown and startup sequences, the above log messages seem to indicate that PostgreSQL is writing *and completing* a final checkpoint before shutdown, and then successfully shutting down.

However, based on the code at xlog.c line 6023 and xlog.c line 6503 (https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/ca9cfed883333d5801716eb01cf28b6b5be2b5cd/src/backend/access/transam/xlog.c; can't post more than 2 links), corresponding to the `database system was interrupted [...]` and `database system was not properly shut down [...]` log lines, respectively, it would appear that at least the `pg_control` file was not flushed to disk. This worries me, as I'm expecting Amazon have taken care to make sure that the volumes on which PostgreSQL data and log files are stored are fit-for-purpose (i.e. they don't report `fsync` completion until it is really complete).

Is there another explanation for this behavior?

Comment: Yeah, that's odd, and concerning. Ask AWS support and report back?

Comment: I'm not sure lack of reliable fsync() would explain it though, I'd expect to see a variety of weird intermittent corruption problems from that. It's hard to imagine that would go unnoticed.

Comment: @CraigRinger, the issue has been reported to the software development manager for RDS PostgreSQL. It may not be due to reliable `fsync`, that's just my hypothesis. It's also possible the instance terminates before the database engine can `fsync` the `pg_control` file. My understanding is that `fsync` reporting success _before_ the data is actually written to disk is not unheard of: some drive controllers cache writes. I suspect RDS PostgreSQL uses EBS, which is SAN (or SAN like), which complicates things.

Comment: As you're not using an open source software, it's difficult to say...

My guess is that by default, stopping RDS Postgres issues a "immediate" stop whereas Postgres simply issues a "fast" stop. That means the instance can't do a checkpoint before stopping and so it has to do it on startup. (And stopping in "immediate" mode is exactly like crashing the instance FYI)

Comment: As of the timestamp of this comment stopped RDS instances still require recovery on startup. This is for an instance on version 10.6, not 9.6.3 as was the case in the original question, but I doubt this has anything to do with the PostgreSQL version and everything to do with RDS.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this ?

Comment: Did you notice the "last known up at 2017-10-12 16:37:50 UTC"?  That's 14 seconds after the shutdown from your logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [answer](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=809401&#809401) to this question was provided on the AWS Developer Forums thread to which it was originally posted.

**Summary**

RDS PostgreSQL (as of the versions available in April 2018) doesn't always recover after restart; however, if the RDS instance does not shutdown within an unspecified timeout, RDS will force terminate the instance, requiring PostgreSQL to recover on reboot.

**Full text of reply**

> Thanks for using RDS!
>
> I saw this thread referenced somewhere else and thought I'd give a quick input. I work closely with the PostgreSQL service team and I can confirm that the behavior you're observing is correct. As of today (April 2018) it's the case that sometimes, if shutdown hasn't completed quickly enough, the RDS automation will time-out and force termination. Various behaviors like this have in fact existed for a long time, so you may have observed it before. In the handful of specific cases that have been discussed on this thread, I can't really comment on why PostgreSQL (or other database engines) took longer than usual to shut down - there are probably many different possible causes for this.
>
> To be clear, the specifics about if and how and when a force-termination occurs might change over time depending on many variables. What will never change is the RDS team's commitment to durability and availability of customers' data. Meaning that (1) our engineers carefully design with safety in mind, avoiding things that might increase risk of corruption in any way and (2) our engineers are always mindful that downtime - whether measured in minutes or seconds or milliseconds - is worth minimizing as far as safely possible.
>
> I hope this helps, to hear that what you're observing is there by design!
>
> -Jeremy